# Using php var inside js file

Tags: javascript, jquery, laravel, variables

I'm using Laravel's var `({{ $test }})`, assets `({{ asset('upload/img/something.png' }})`, route `( {{ route('something.something') }} )` in a js script. This script works correctly if its in a blade file.

I want to has this script inside a js file. I know that I can create a js function and call this in a blade file with arguments, but I have no more arguments. How I can solve my problem?

Comment: please add the code you have tried

Comment: Make an object of your arguments and send the object as the single argument.

Answer (score 2):

You can declare your variables in blade file, then include the javascript file to use them.

**Example:**
In your blade file you declare a url variable:

```
<script>
   var url = "{{ route('something.something') }}";
</script>
```

*Notice that we use var so that the variable will be visible in the scripts below this.*

Then you include your script file:

```
<script src="{{ asset('js/myScript.js' }}"></script>
```

In that file you can use the url variable.

PS: maybe if you provide more code I will be able to help you more.